# How to create a runat server DIV in the behind code ? ASP.NET & C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating multiple DIVs according to database records at my C# behind code. How could I make them runat server ?

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 9):

Create and add [ASP.NET `Panels`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx).

The code

```
<asp:Panel id="abc" runat="server">
```

is exactly the same as if you do:

```
<div id="abc" runat="server">
```

They render the same, but it's the functionality with other **WebControls** that the Panel is most used, and the Panel web control gives you more control under code-behind as it exposes more properties.

If you want to access a `DIV` on serverside, you could also add `runat="server"`. It will be created as `HtmlGenericControl`.

Comment: Thank you, Tim. I was hunting for this very thing and came across your excellent example and explanation.

Answer (score 4):

That's not necessary, just create a `HtmlGenericControl` and add it to the controls collection:

```
HtmlGenericControl div = HtmlGenericControl("div")
div.Id = "myid";
this.Controls.Add(div);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom control that pulls the data and renders it how you would like. Kind of like this:

```
public class MyDivControl : System.Web.UI.Control
{
    private System.Data.DataTable tblMyResults;
    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        // Get your Data (or do it on Page_Load if you'll need it more than once
        if (tblMyResults != null && tblMyResults.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int iIndex = 0;
            foreach (System.Data.DataRow rItem in tblMyResults.Rows)
            {
                writer.WriteLine("<div id=\"{0}_{1}\">", this.ClientID, iIndex++);
                //Whatever content you want here using your rows.
                writer.WriteLine("</div>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then just drop the control on the page where you want it to render.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Solution.Web.Presentation.pub._default" MasterPageFile="~/ui/master/main.master" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="custom" Namespace="MyNameSpace" Assembly="MyProjectAssembly" %>
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="cntMain">

<custom:MyDivControl runat="server" />

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Repeater Control

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <div id="box<%# Eval("ID")%>" runat="server"></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and bind data from codebehind